# Pre-loading images with a twist for Ionic Cordova app

Tags: angularjs, image, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic Cordova app.

On load I get a dictionary which contains a slew of users and their profile picture URIs. The twist is that the images change all the time, but their URIs remain the same.

Right now on every cycle I just reload the image, but as you can image I'm having some severe performance issues.

What I want to somehow do is pre-load the images, but continue polling the picture URIs in the background and update the image cache when there's a new image to pull (this happens frequently). The images are displayed in an ng-repeat.

I've looked at Ionic's $imageCacheFactory and it doesn't look like it'll do what I need, nor do any of the other cache plugins I've seen out there.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your server is set up to return a `304` when an image hasn't changed (I would expect this), I would approach using the following method:

1. Create an attribute directive, e.g. `volatile-img-src`, whose value is either an interpolated URL or an expression evaluating to a URL.
2. Have the directive look at another attribute value that corresponds to a refresh interval, but make it optional with a sensible default.
3. Initially just set the `src` of the image like `ng-src` does, but subsequently start your polling using `$interval`.

Your poll mechanism would look something like this:

```
$interval( function() {
  $http.get(imageUrl).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      if (data.status === 200){
        // This doesn't happen if the code is a 304.
        reloadImage();
      }
    });
    // TODO: your own error handling.
}, pollFrequency);
```

I assume from your question that you don't need help with the reload part.